# BigQuery: IFNULL after an UPDATE column, then "LIV"

Tags: google-bigquery, gpc

Im new in all of this and Im having a dificult time doing the following:
After an Alter Table where Im adding a new column Im updating the values based on another column. What a want to do is where there is a null after the process put the name "LIV".

How would you do it?

Thanks in advance

Code:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST1 ADD COLUMN UBIC2 STRING;
UPDATE TEST1 
SET UBIC2 = UBIC
WHERE ZONA ="X1" or ZONA ="X2"
```

Tried to use an IFNULL(UBIC2, "LIV")

Answer (score 0):

You could update the table with a `case` expression. Also, since you want to update **all** the rows of the table, you can lose the `where` clause:

```sql
UPDATE test1
SET    ubic2 = CASE WHEN zona IN ('X1', 'X2') THEN ubic ELSE 'LIV' END
```

Comment: Tried it, but sends an error Query error: UPDATE must have a WHERE clause at [2:1]

Answer (score 0):

Tried this ?

```
UPDATE test1
SET    ubic2 = CASE WHEN zona IN ('X1', 'X2') THEN ubic ELSE 'LIV' END
where 1=1
```